# Angular.js: validation error is not removing on deleting a duplicate row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

duplicate_error[image: duplicate_error 2]I have a table with two column "user type" and "user Name" User type having a drop down selection So that i can select predefined user type and place a name in User name. There is a Add button on each click i am adding one another row.

I am doing one validation here So that user can't selected repeated "User type". for example from row 1 is i select "value 1" from drop down. then from row 2 i should not be able to select same value. Anyway this validation works fine. but there is one scenario if I add a duplicate row, then remove it right away, I am still unable to save because the validation error is still there.

Even i am calling that revalidate() function from delete button it doesn't solved my issue.

I think it might because the revalidate function keeps setting and re-setting the validity of the same model, so the validity of the model triggering method invocation will be based on the last comparison result and that apply to the same row which row was deleted.

My doubt here is how to validate row data with other on delete button, means is there any way to pass complete Object collection as a whole and recheck.
Please help me out as i have no clue whatsoever how to proceed from here.
@CSS-

```
     input.ng-invalid, select.ng-invalid {
       border-color: #843534;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 6px #ce8483;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 6px #ce8483;
       box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 6px #ce8483;
```

}

my html-

```
    <div ng-class="{'col-sm-9'}" class="col-md-10">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <th>user type</th>
            <th>user Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="object in edituserConfig track by $index" ng-form="jobfileForm">
                <td><select class="form-control" ng-model="object.key" required ng-change="reValidateJob()"  name="jobFileKey" ng-init="object.form = jobfileForm">

                        <option style="display:none" value=""></option>
                        <option value="value1">value1t</option>
                        <option value="value2">value2</option>
                        <option value="value3">value3</option>
                        <option value="value4">value4</option>
                        <option value="value5">value5</option>
                </select></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="jobFileName" ng-model="object.value" required/></td>

                <td >
                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-style="zoom-in" ng-click="edituserConfig.splice($index,1)" ng-form="jobfileForm" title="Delete">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                      </button>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="edituserConfig.push({'key':'','value':''})"    title="Add Value">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Value
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

My controller-

```
         $scope.reValidateJob = function(){

            angular.forEach($scope.edituserConfig, function(fieldMapO) {
                var count = 0;
                angular.forEach($scope.edituserConfig, function(fieldMapI) {
                    if(fieldMapO.key == fieldMapI.key){
                        count ++;
                    }
                });
                if(count >1){
                    fieldMapO.form.jobFileKey.$setValidity("duplicate",false);
                }else{
                    fieldMapO.form.jobFileKey.$setValidity("duplicate",true);
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a call to `reValidateJob()` in the `ng-click` attribute of your delete button should solve the problem.

I created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg17cw4d/2/) to demonstrate it basically works. It uses Angular 1.5.0 and "controller as" syntax instead of your scope, but this should not make any difference with regard to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As said the @lex82, you need to run a function `reValidateJob` every time you delete a line.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/erjxxajp/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.edituserConfig = [];
  $scope.log = $log;

  $scope.remove = function(index) {
    $scope.edituserConfig.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.reValidateJob();
  }
  $scope.reValidateJob = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.edituserConfig, function(fieldMapO) {
      var count = 0;
      angular.forEach($scope.edituserConfig, function(fieldMapI) {
        if (fieldMapO.key == fieldMapI.key) {
          count++;
        }
      });
      if (count > 1) {
        fieldMapO.form.jobFileKey.$setValidity("duplicate", false);
      } else {
        fieldMapO.form.jobFileKey.$setValidity("duplicate", true);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-class="{'col-sm-9':true}" class="col-md-10">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <th>user type</th>
          <th>user Name</th>
          <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="object in edituserConfig" ng-form="jobfileForm">
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" ng-model="object.key" required ng-change="reValidateJob()" name="jobFileKey" ng-init="object.form = jobfileForm">

                <option style="display:none" value=""></option>
                <option value="value1">value1t</option>
                <option value="value2">value2</option>
                <option value="value3">value3</option>
                <option value="value4">value4</option>
                <option value="value5">value5</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jobFileName" ng-model="object.value" required/>
            </td>

            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-style="zoom-in" ng-click="remove($index)" ng-form="jobfileForm" title="Delete">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
              </button>
              <pre>{{object.form.jobFileKey.$error}}</pre>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="edituserConfig.push({'key':'','value':''})" title="Add Value">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Value
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But even validation is pass am getting this error. I have attached screeshot with my question

Comment: added css for vaidation select in my post

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own validation directive which `require`s `ngModel` and adds a validation rule into it. In this case your validation will be run each time the value changes.