# AngularJs: form initialization in ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here am initializing form with model object. **ng-init="object.form = jobfileForm"** 
But i dont want to to implement like this cos it executes only once when controller loads. What are the other ways to do implement this?

```
   <tr ng-repeat="object in editProductJobFile track by $index" ng-form="jobfileForm">
                    <td><select class="form-control" ng-model="object.key" required 
                    ng-change="reValidateJobFileKey(editProductJobFile)"  name="jobFileKey" ng-init="object.form = jobfileForm">
                            <option style="display:none" value=""></option>
                            <option value="somevalue">ffff</option>
                            <option value="valueq">dddd</option>
                            <option value="ababa">ssss</option>
                            <option value="aababab">ss</option>
                            <option value="ssjjs">aa</option>
                    </select></td>
                    </tr>
```

cos form is getting undefined whener my view is changing!
Any suggestion??

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your ng-init?

Comment: Hello Wawy, 
I did some validation check in my dropdown selection and it worked fine. and deleting a row is also working for the 1st time. Since i am initializing my form name in ng-init. So after saving the data for the 1st time am redirecting to another page. again while comming to the current page and tried to  I delete a row throwing some error of undefined .. Please refer my ;ast post. I have given my complete scenario there, but dint get any answer so reposted here with sort desciption-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967303/angular-ng-form-is-getting-undefined-when-view-changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular.js: validation error is not removing on deleting a duplicate row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902503/angular-js-validation-error-is-not-removing-on-deleting-a-duplicate-row)